# Pass parameter in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have 2 visualforce page, I am redirecting from 1 visualforce page to another visualforce page. And I am passing parameter as below from page 1.

```
string paramVal = 'someValue';

PageReference secondPageurl = new PageReference('/apex/secondPage?cyid='+ paramVal); secondPageurl.setRedirect(true); return secondPageurl;
```

When I open site in normal system browser (chrome/IE/etc) I am able to get cyid value, but when I am using Salesforce1 app, on second page I am not getting cyid value.

How can I pass parameter to 2nd page in salesforce1 app.

Comment: How are you doing navigation in SF1. In the normal scenario, we get the values from param.

Comment: I am redirecting to visualforce page using pagereference.

Comment: I can confirm that this should work as I am also using this. Can you share controller code as well?

Comment: On second page I am using below code to get parameter.    string strCYid =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cyid');

Comment: When I Use above statement, it works fine in desktop browser but parameter strCYid is null in Salesforce1 App.

Answer (score 0):

The Visualforce page must have the "Available for Salesforce Mobile Apps" checkbox selected. See below,
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187793&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: "Available for Salesforce Mobile Apps" checkbox is selected. And I am able to move to 2nd page, but I am not able to get the parameters on second page.

Comment: I tried to replicate the scenario creating two pages and tried sending params from one page to other, did not face any issues. Have you tested this scenarios in Classic or Lightning context in Browser? Kindly test the same in Lightning context.

Based on the value of $User.UIThemeDisplayed you can put your redirection logic.

Comment: I have a custom object with record types, and I have overriden "new" button with visualforce page. based upon recordtype selection I am redirecting to VF page. When I open new CO in salesforce1 app, the record types are displayed in default classic theme, but in system browser it is lightning theme. So it is like this SF1-> Classic to Lightning. And Chrome-> lightning.